# searching/filtering a list with react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter, redux

I'm currently learning react and redux and stumbled into a problem i can't really get my head around. Trying to implement the same functionality
as in this article: https://medium.com/@yaoxiao1222/implementing-search-filter-a-list-on-redux-react-bb5de8d0a3ad but even though the data request from the rest api i'm working with is successfull i can't assign the local state in my component to my redux-state, in order to be able to filter my results. Heres my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import * as fetchActions from '../../actions/fetchActions'
import Stafflist from './Stafflist'

class AboutPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search: '',
      currentlyDisplayed: this.props.store.posts
    }
    this.updateSearch = this.updateSearch.bind(this)
  }
  updateSearch(event) {
    let newlyDisplayed = this.state.currentlyDisplayed.filter(
      (post) => { 
        return (
          post.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          || post.role.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        )}
    )
    console.log(newlyDisplayed)
    this.setState({
      search: event.target.value.substr(0, 20),
      currentlyDisplayed: newlyDisplayed
    })
  }
  render() {
     return (
      <div className="about-page">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <input type="text"
          value={this.state.search}
          onChange={this.updateSearch}
        />
        //component for rendering my list of posts.
        <Stafflist posts={this.state.currentlyDisplayed} />
      </div>
     )
  }
}
// this is here i assign my api data to this.props.store.posts
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    store: state
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(fetchActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AboutPage)
```

Comparing how i assign my stores state to my local component with how it works in the article, it seems to be done in the same way. Mine:

```
this.state = {
   search: '',
   currentlyDisplayed: this.props.store.posts
}
```

article:

```
this.state = {
   searchTerm: '',
   currentlyDisplayed: this.props.people
}
```

within react devtools i can see my data in as it should be in the store, but it won't work to assign it to my local state within the component in order to perform the filtering, and i don't really know how to debug this. My state in the local component just says

```
 State
 currentlyDisplayed: Array[0]
 Empty array
```

also if i change

```
<Stafflist posts={this.state.currentlyDisplayed} />
```

to

```
<Stafflist posts={this.props.store.posts} />
```

the list renders as it should :)

Reducer:

```
 import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'
 import initialState from './initialState'


 export default function postReducer(state = initialState.posts, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
   case types.FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS:
     return action.posts.data.map(post => {
       return {
         id: post.id,
         name: post.acf.name,
         role: post.acf.role
       }
     })     
   default:
     return state
   }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you are missing `state` in `this.currentlyDisplayed.filter`. It should be `this.state.currentlyDisplayed.filter()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you do not handle how to get newly received props to your state. This means that when you receive the data from your api call only the props are updated while component state is not.

If you look carefully at the referenced article, in the onInputChange method they recalculate the state from the props whereas your updateState method only filters from the local state.

Setting the state in the constructor only ensures that the props are copied on the initial mount of the component. At that point in time the store only contains the initial state (initialState.posts in your reducer code). This is the price of keeping both component state and store; you must think of how to keep the two in sync after the initial load.

One solution is to update the state in componentWillReceiveProps:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  const nextFiltered = nextProps.store.posts.filter(your filtering code here);
  this.setState({currentlyDisplayed: nextFiltered});
}
```

This will update your state whenever the component receives new props. Note react has phased out componentWillReceiveProps and you should use getDerivedStateToProps as of react 16.3. Refer [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to read my code! if i change the updateSearch function to filter on this.props.store.posts.filter(....) you're right, as i start typing the search function works as expected, but in the initial state the list is not populated. How should i populate the list with the initial props if it is not done with this.state = {currentlyDisplayed:  this.props.store.posts}?

Comment: Edited the answer to clear things up. To be honest I don't agree with the original article. Filtering using state is messy and can be done by store and props alone. Consider researching other methods for your goal.